# Show that f is continous at $(0,0)$ where $ f(x,y)= y\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ if $x \neq 0$ else $0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

> Show that f is continous at $(0,0)$ where $ f(x,y)= y\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ if $x \neq 0$ else $0$

$f(0,0)=0$

$0\leq |\sin(\frac{1}{x})|\leq 1$ $\Rightarrow$
$0 \leq |y\sin(\frac{1}{x})| \leq |y|$

now we have $y \to 0$ because$(x,y) \to (0,0)$
therefore by squeeze theorem $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} |y\sin(\frac{1}{x})| = 0 $
$\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} y\sin(\frac{1}{x}) = 0 $

function value and limit is equal so continuous...

I am new to multivariable calculus... I wanted to ask if I have done this rightly particularly have I applied the squeeze theorem correctly?

Comment: A little correction that you need to take $lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}$ from both sides, so $lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} |y| = 0$, instead of just $lim_{y \to 0} |y| = 0$. Otherwise it's alright.

Comment: Just a comment : $y \to 0$ is not enough to have the result you're looking for. You mush show that $f(x,y) \to 0$ as $\Vert (x,y) \Vert \to 0$ (which is a stronger condition than only $y \to 0$). Considering what you've done, I would just add:

$$ 0 \leq \vert f(x,y) \vert \leq \vert y \vert \leq \Vert (x,y) \Vert_{2} $$

which allows you to conclude using the Squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Stefan4024 thanks edited.

Comment: @jibounet thank you, I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$

such that  $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} \lt \delta$ implies

$|y\sin(1/x)| \lt \epsilon.$

Choose $\delta = \epsilon$.

$|y\sin(1/x)| \le |y| \le (x^2+y^2)^{1/2} \lt \delta =\epsilon.$

Your solution is fine, above a little more formal.